# Как прижать картинку к низу? flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Как мне прижать картинку к низу вплотную?

```
Scaffold(
  body: SafeArea(
    // bottom: false,
    maintainBottomViewPadding: false,
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text('Settings'),
        Text('Help'),
        Text('Privacy Policy'),
        Text('Terms of Use'),
        Text('Support'),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
          child: Container(
              height: 638.57,
              width: 375,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                  alignment: Alignment(0, 0),
                  image: AssetImage(Images.background_1),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover
                ),
              ),
            ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавить [spacer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Spacer-class.html) или обернуть в еще один `Column` и установить у него `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween`